# unescape unicode from input 

Tags: java, unicode, escaping, character

I am reading line by line from standard input with Scanner, then i print these lines to standard output. But, i need to convert escaped Unicode characters like \u00fd to actual character. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Are users typing in `"\u00fd"`, or `ý`? There are already a number of questions on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630609, to start.

Comment: The input is \u00fd, i need to get ý, but i am getting \u00fd

Comment: A good place to start.  http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html.