# Regular Expression to match ([^>(),]+) but include some \w's in it?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using php's preg_replace function, and I have the following regex:

```
(?:[^>(),]+)
```

to match any characters but `>(),`. The problem is that I want to make sure that there is at least one letter in it (`\w`) and the match is not empty, how can I do that?

Is there a way to say what i DO WANT to match in the `[^>(),]+` part?

Comment: You should probably expression functionnally what you want to do ? If you want to look for non-empty words, you can simply use `\w+`

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want them included in that exact sequence?

Comment: I'll be more specific. I have the following exp:

$exp = " div.class#id > table( tr > td > lable, tr > td > input value=\$val  )";
And want to be able to match these:

(div.class#id)
(table)
(tr, etc...)
(input value=$val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:(?=.*\p{L})[^>(),]+)
```

This makes sure that there will be at least one letter (`\p{L}`; `\w` also matches digits and underscores) somewhere in the string.

You don't really need the `(?:...)` non-capturing parentheses, though:

```
(?=.*\p{L})[^>(),]+
```

works just as well. Also, to ensure that we always match the entire string, it might be a good idea to surround the regex with anchors:

```
^(?=.*\p{L})[^>(),]+$
```

EDIT:

For the added requirement of not including surrounding whitespace in the match, things get a little more complicated. Try

```
^(?=.*\p{L})(\s*)((?:(?!\s*$)[^>(),])+)(\s*)$
```

In PHP, for example to replace all those strings we found with `REPLACEMENT`, leaving leading and trailing whitespace alone, this could look like this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/^          # Start of string
    (?=.*\p{L})  # Assert that there is at least one letter
    (\s*)        # Match and capture optional leading whitespace  (--> \1)
    (            # Match and capture...                           (--> \2)
     (?:         # ...at least one character of the following:
      (?!\s*$)   # (unless it is part of trailing whitespace)
      [^>(),]    # any character except >(),
     )+          # End of repeating group
    )            # End of capturing group
    (\s*)        # Match and capture optional trailing whitespace (--> \3)
    $            # End of string
    /xu', 
    '\1REPLACEMENT\3', $subject);
```

Comment: in *perl* at least, this doesn't work quite as specified by the OQ.  For example, the string "123(p" passes the lookahead assertion (due to matching .*p) but fails the requirement that the captured group include the p (it doesn't).  I may have misunderstood the php requirements.

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to stop the engine matching whitespaces \s at the end. I mean, it can be at the middle but not at end or begining?

Comment: @Alex Brown: You're right; it's probably a good idea to use some anchors here. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @Fábio: Do you mean that you want the match to fail if there is whitespace at the front/end, or do you want the match to succeed but without adding the surrounding whitespace to the match?

Comment: I want to match the succeed but without adding the whitespace, exactly. I've already tried (?!\s+) as i've seen explained in the page of the link you gave me, but no success

Comment: @tchrist: I know. My statement is still correct (although not complete). And since I recommended against `\w` anyway, I thought that this level of detail would have been too much at this point.

Comment: @Tim, `\w` is a lot broader than “also digits and underscores.” In regex dialects that support set union and intersection operations on bracketed character classes, a `\w` is equivalent to `[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]`. That’s how you have to write in Java, which has no `\w` support for Unicode. That makes `\b` extremely awkward to write.

Comment: @Tim, Agreed. You need the detail only in languages without Unicode support for the charclass shortcuts. A Unicode `\b` in Java must be written `(?:(?<=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])|(?<![\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]])(?=[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Pc}[\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}&&\p{So}]]))`, which is horrid.

Comment: `\b` is just `(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))`, but those `\w`’s need expansion into an unsightliness that makes the Unicode whitespace pattern in Java downright friendly: `[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0020\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u2028\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]`, eh? :)

Comment: Lastly, `\B` is really `(?:(?<=\w)(?=\w)|(?<!\w)(?!\w))`. I often find `\b` not quite what I want, preferring instead `(?:(?<=^)|(?<=\s))` for a left edge and `(?=$|\s)` for a right edge. Those aren’t quite so weird as `\b`, but you do have to specify left vs right; in practice, this is no different than having to distinguish `^` vs `$`.

Comment: @tchrist: This is fascinating. I will ask a question about this and would be grateful if you could provide a similar exhaustive answer there. This makes reading (and bookmarking) this important piece of knowledge easier.

Comment: @Tim: Sure thing.  Most of my knowledge you can glean from reading [this answer’s source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836), which I posted yesterday answering an old question (and which nobody but me has yet looked at, darn it). But if you ask a question with the `regex` tag, I’ll find it when I get to work in an hour and answer with a much more distilled summary of all the exact mappings for `\w \W \s \S \v \V \h \H \d \D \b \B \X \R`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just "insert" `\w` inside `(?:[^>(),]+\w[^>(),]+)`. So it will have at least one letter and obviously not empty. BTW `\w` captures digits as well as letters. If you want only letters you can use unicode letter character class `\p{L}` instead of `\w`.

Comment: hmmm, thats so simple, how didn't I figure it out! Yes, i just wanted to make sure that there was at least one letter in the match

Comment: This is slightly stricter than the OQ, since it permits .A. but not .A A. or A

Comment: @Alex Brown: yes, you are right, stars should be used instead of pluses.

Comment: Actually, [according to Unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties), `\w` comprises `\pL` all *Letters,* `\pM` all *Marks,* `\p{Nd}` the *Decimal Numbers,* the `\p{Nl}` the *Letter Numbers,* `\p{Pc}` the *Connector Punctuation,* plus all code points which are both `\p{InEnclosedAlphanumerics}` and also `\p{So}`, the *Other Symbols.*

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(?:[^>(),]*\w[^>(),]*)
```

Comment: I slightly modified yours so this would work for me: (?:[^>(),]*\p{L}[^>(),]*)