# how to parse unicode that is read from a file in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, text-files, fileinputstream

I have written a text file with the following contents: `\u0032\u0142o\u017Cy\u0142`

Then I have used FileReader und BufferedReader to read the file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream("README.TXT");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8"));
   String s="";
   while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

But the output is: `\u0032\u0142o\u017Cy\u0142`.

When I used

```
System.out.println("\u0032\u0142o\u017Cy\u0142");
```

These codes will be parsed and will be shown in the right form.

How can I change my code, so that unicode from the files will also be parsed and shown in the right form?

Comment: Does you file contains the actual caracters for '\u0032' or does it contains the literal string "\u0032"?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. It contains \u0032\u0142o\u017Cy\u0142 without quotation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the source code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836) to do unescaping.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [sun.tools.native2ascii](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) to reverse convert the text.

```
new sun.tools.native2ascii.Main().convert(new String[]{"-reverse", new File("README.TXT"), convertedFile});
```

So something like this will do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
   File convertedFile = new File("converted.txt");
   new sun.tools.native2ascii.Main().convert(new String[]{"-reverse", new File("README.TXT"), convertedFile});
   FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(convertedFile);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr,"UTF-8"));
   String s="";
   while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parsing of unicode escape sequences is not an explicit part of the Java Standard API, it only implicitly occurs when loading `Properties`. You could copy the implementation from the source code of `Properties`.

But it would be better to use a normal encoding like UTF-8 for your file.