# Convert International String to \u Codes in java

Tags: java, unicode, escaping, unicode-escapes

How can I convert an international (e.g. Russian) String to `\u` numbers (unicode numbers)
e.g. `\u041e\u041a` for `OK` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you need this to write a `.properties` file you can just add the Strings into a Properties object and then save it to a file. It will take care for the conversion.

Comment: Well you need to make sure that you save the file in UTF-8 format (perhaps UTF-16 or UCS-2/4 will work) or you will have problems.

Comment: @ArtB: No, Properties interprets input files always as `ISO-8859-1` (first unicode page) and also saves to that encoding. This is why it needs the `\uXXXX` escapes and creates them on saving. Although since Java version 1.6 Properties allows to read the input from a Reader object so that you would be able to make your own proprietary UTF-8 based properties file format.

Comment: Oh... doesn't that cause problems with non-first page languages?

Comment: Yes, it results in comparatively large files for languages that use mostly characters outside 8859-1 the because the `\uXXXX` encoding is less space efficient than UTF-8 or UTF-16. It also makes it impossible to edit these files in any editor that is not aware of this special encoding. But at least it allows to save and load all unicode text to the extend that is supported by the Java VM in general.

Comment: @x4u I am not sure that \u notation will support Unicode characters outside Unicode BMP.

Comment: That's why I wrote *to the extend that is supported by the Java VM in general*. Actually it supports characters outside the BMP since Java treats these characters as surrogate pairs and thus they can be encoded in a \u pair as well. But the level of support for surrogates varies a lot in Java, from mostly nonexistent to somewhat supported in XML-Parsers or some Swing components. Also many of the basic String manipulation routines in java.lang seem to be surrogates aware by now (except for regexp as far as I know) but you can still cut a string in the middle of them if you like.

Comment: This seems like a really round-about solution.  From the question, I assumed we were looking for some kind of method call String->String.

Answer (score 62):

there is a [JDK tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) executed via command line as following :

```
native2ascii -encoding utf8 src.txt output.txt
```

Example :

**src.txt**

```
بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
```

**output.txt**

```
\u0628\u0633\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062d\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062d\u064a\u0645
```

If you want to use it in your Java application, you can wrap this command line by :

```
String pathSrc = "./tmp/src.txt";
String pathOut = "./tmp/output.txt";
String cmdLine = "native2ascii -encoding utf8 " + new File(pathSrc).getAbsolutePath() + " " + new File(pathOut).getAbsolutePath();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdLine);
System.out.println("THE END");
```

Then read  content of the new file.

Comment: You can do it without starting a subprocess, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6017769/115493

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/ulisseslima/d614a31b73947471e04176b0951527bd) wraps the command line example above in a Bash script so it's easier to use.

Comment: This tool was removed in Java 9: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400023/what-happened-to-native2ascii-executable-in-java-9

Comment: So what's the alterntive now that `native2ascii` is gone?

Answer (score 24):

You could use `escapeJavaStyleString` from `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`.

Comment: It appears this method has been renamed [`escapeJava`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) in the 3.x versions

Comment: and doesn't escape to \uXXXX

Comment: You better not use it ;) See the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4298836/115493

Comment: This method also escapes other special symbols, eg. quote ("). This may be an unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 16):

I also had this problem. I had some Portuguese text with some special characters, but these characters where already in unicode format (ex.: `\u00e3`).

So I want to convert `S\u00e3o` to `São`.

I did it using the apache commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html). As @sorin-sbarnea said. Can be downloaded [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi).

Use the method `unescapeJava`, like this:

```
String text = "S\u00e3o"
text = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text);
System.out.println("text " + text);
```

(There is also the method `escapeJava`, but this one puts the unicode characters in the string.)

If any one knows a solution on pure Java, please tell us.

Comment: You're doing it the other way round, that's not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an improved version of [ArtB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230386/254477):

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 128)
            b.append("\\u").append(String.format("%04X", (int) c));
        else
            b.append(c);
    }

    return b.toString();
```

This version escapes all non-ASCII chars and works correctly for low Unicode code points like `Ä`.

Comment: does it work for multibyte characters, e.g. when 4-6-8 bytes (2, 3, 4 java **char** values) in a row represent only one symbol?

Comment: It doesn't, because it's iterating using a single `char`.

Answer (score 12):

There are three parts to the answer

1. Get the Unicode for each character
2. Determine if it is in the Cyrillic Page
3. Convert to Hexadecimal.

To get each character you can iterate through the String using the [`charAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) or [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) methods.

```
for( char c : s.toCharArray() )
```

The value of the char is the Unicode value.

The [Cyrillic Unicode](http://www.google.ca/search?q=unicode%20cyrillic&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=nxPpTcLfDIOFtgfN5NS_AQ) characters are any character in the following ranges:

```
Cyrillic:            U+0400–U+04FF ( 1024 -  1279)
Cyrillic Supplement: U+0500–U+052F ( 1280 -  1327)
Cyrillic Extended-A: U+2DE0–U+2DFF (11744 - 11775)
Cyrillic Extended-B: U+A640–U+A69F (42560 - 42655)
```

If it is in this range it is Cyrillic. Just perform an if check. If it is in the range use `Integer.toHexString()` and prepend the `"\\u"`. Put together it should look something like this:

```
final int[][] ranges = new int[][]{ 
        {  1024,  1279 }, 
        {  1280,  1327 }, 
        { 11744, 11775 }, 
        { 42560, 42655 },
    };
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

for( char c : s.toCharArray() ){
    int[] insideRange = null;
    for( int[] range : ranges ){
        if( range[0] <= c && c <= range[1] ){
            insideRange = range;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( insideRange != null ){
        b.append( "\\u" ).append( Integer.toHexString(c) );
    }else{
        b.append( c );
    }
}

return b.toString();
```

---

**Edit:** probably should make the check `c < 128` and reverse the `if` and the `else` bodies; you *probably* should escape everything that isn't ASCII. I was probably too literal in my reading of your question.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my context. 
However, I believe "getCharArray()" should be "toCharArray".

Comment: @JenS. Thank you, indeed, the method is in fact [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

Comment: This isn't correct for all Unicode characters! e.g. for German `Ä` it returns `\uC4`, not `\u00c4`.

Comment: @m01 I believe the original form of the question was specifically about Russian characters.

Comment: Russian was given just as an example. Your example is ok though; the range checks in the if guard against this case. See also my answer for a generic approach.

Comment: "The value of the char is the Unicode value." Yes but more specifically, it is the UTF-16 code-unit value, with one or two UTF-16 code-units per Unicode codepoint. UTF-16 code-units _are_ what you need to construct [Java source code character escapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) (whether used in literal strings or not).

Answer (score 7):

There's a command-line tool that ships with java called [native2ascii](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html). This converts unicode files to ASCII-escaped files. I've found that this is a necessary step for generating .properties files for localization.

Answer (score 6):

Apache commons `StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(String)` returns a string with unicode characters escaped using the `\u` notation.

```
"Art of Beer  " -> "Art of Beer \u1F3A8 \u1F37A"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: This very useful library. It solved my problem for converting from cyrillic to unicode. Thank you Michael.

Comment: @Zafer I am glad the library helped you. Can I ask you a small favor? could you please got to the article about my library and leave a comment? Here are 2 links: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/, https://community.oracle.com/blogs/michaelgantman/2016/01/26/open-source-java-library-with-stacktrace-filtering-silent-string-parsing-and-version-comparison

Answer (score 3):

Just some basic Methods for that (inspired from native2ascii tool):

```
/**
 * Encode a String like äöü to \u00e4\u00f6\u00fc
 * 
 * @param text
 * @return
 */
public String native2ascii(String text) {
    if (text == null)
        return text;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(native2ascii(ch));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Encode a Character like ä to \u00e4
 * 
 * @param ch
 * @return
 */
public String native2ascii(char ch) {
    if (ch > '\u007f') {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // write \udddd
        sb.append("\\u");
        StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer(Integer.toHexString(ch));
        hex.reverse();
        int length = 4 - hex.length();
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            hex.append('0');
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            sb.append(hex.charAt(3 - j));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return Character.toString(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably hack if from this JavaScript code:

```
/* convert  to \uD83D\uDE4C */
function text_to_unicode(string) {
  'use strict';

  function is_whitespace(c) { return 9 === c || 10 === c || 13 === c || 32 === c;  }
  function left_pad(string) { return Array(4).concat(string).join('0').slice(-1 * Math.max(4, string.length)); }

  string = string.split('').map(function(c){ return "\\u" + left_pad(c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()); }).join('');

  return string;
}


/* convert \uD83D\uDE4C to  */
function unicode_to_text(string) {
  var  prefix = "\\\\u"
     , regex  = new RegExp(prefix + "([\da-f]{4})","ig")
     ; 

  string = string.replace(regex, function(match, backtrace1){
    return String.fromCharCode( parseInt(backtrace1, 16) )
  });

  return string;
}
```

source: [iCompile - Yet Another JavaScript Unicode Encode/Decode](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/yet-another-javascript-unicode-encodedecode/)

Answer (score 0):

this type name is Decode/Unescape Unicode.
this [site link](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) online convertor.