# Alfresco localization encoding

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Trying to create custom types, aspects and properties for Alfresco, I followed the [Alfresco Developer Series](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-content/content-article-2ed.pdf) guide. When I reached the **localization** section I found out that Alfresco does not handle UTF-8 encoding in the .properties files that you create. Greek characters are not displayed correctly in Share.

Checking out other built-in .properties files (/opt/alfresco-4.0.e/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/messages) I noticed that in Japanese, for example, the characters are in this notation: \u3059\u3079\u3066\u306e...

So, the question is: do I have to convert the greek words in the above mentioned notation for Share to display them correctly, or is there another -more elegant- way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The \u#### form is the Java form of the [Unicode Escape Sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1), and is used to reference unicode characters without having to worry about the encoding of the file storing them.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java) has some information on how to create and decode them

Another way, which is what Alfresco developers tend to use, is the [Native2ASCII tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) which ships with Java itself. With that, you can initially write your strings in a UTF-8 (for example) file, then use the tool to turn them into their escaped form.