# escaping Java string to utf-8

Tags: java, utf-8, escaping

I'm looking for java tool for converting regular String to utf-8 string.

> e.g.
>
> input: **special-数据应用-text**
>
> output: **special-%u6570%u636E%u5E94%u7528-text**

(note the preceding "%u")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String s= URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replaceAll("%(..)%(..)", "%u$1$2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The string you want as result is not UTF-8, at least the string you put as example is sort of UTF-16 encoded (java uses UTF-16 internally)
2. An example of code that gives you the string that you want:

   ```
   String str = "special-数据应用-text";

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   for(char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
       if(ch >= 0x20 && ch <= 0x7E) {
           builder.append(ch);
       } else {
           builder.append(String.format("%%u%04X", (int)ch));
       }
   }

   String result = builder.toString();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

for( char c : s.toCharArray() ){
    if( ( 1024 <= c && c <= 1279 ) || ( 1280 <= c && c <= 1327) || ( 11744 <= c && c <= 11775) || ( 42560 <= c && c <= 42655)  ){
        b.append( "\\u" ).append( Integer.toHexString(c) );
    }else{
        b.append( c );
    }
}

return b.toString();
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend you Unbescape [ http://www.unbescape.org ]

Among other escaping operations (HTML, XML, etc.), it will allow you to escape your Java literal with:

```
final String escaped = JavaEscape.escapeJava(text);
```

Disclaimer, per StackOverflow rules: I'm Unbescape's author.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't need java tool, but needs the online tool here is the tool https://itpro.cz/juniconv/