# Print Unicode characters with hex code loop

Tags: java, string, unicode, hex, unicode-escapes

I'm getting illegal unicode escape for the following code.

```
 for(int i=3400;i<4000;i++)
   System.out.println("\u" + i );
```

If I add a slash before I get `\u3400` as output instead of actual unicode character.

I want to print the unicode characters in a loop. 
Also unicode characters are hex codes. How to loop through hex codes and print all unicode characters.

Comment: Please go through : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot concatenate `"\u"` with something at runtime, because `"\uXXXX"` sequences are parsed during the compilation. However don't need to do this. You can simply cast integers to chars and use `0x` prefix to specify the hex numbers:

```
for(int i=0x3400;i<0x4000;i++)
    System.out.println((char)i);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is something like:

```
    for (int i = 0x3400; i < 0x4000; i++) {
        System.out.println((char) i);
    }
```

You shouldn't forget, that any number after `\u` prefix is hexademical number (radix 16). From this fact follows that in your loop you will lose a lot of unicode characters in hex-interval `3400...4000`. So, you should change loop range to `0x3400` and `0x4000`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) functionality:-

```
for(int i=3400;i<4000;i++){
   System.out.format("\\u%04x", i);
}
```

Or according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220476/5193194) answer use this :-

```
for(int i=3400;i<4000;i++){
   System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(i| 0x10000).substring(1));
}
```