# Spring roo: Showing entity names in Arabic

Tags: spring, internationalization, spring-roo

I used [this](https://github.com/YahyaAlfayad/roo-i18n-arabic) addon to add the Arabic language to my project. It worked fine but I still need to show the entity names in Arabic as well.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity names and properties are defined on `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties`

To create the *porperties-file* for a specific language you can:

- Use a Eclipse plug-in. [The eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/i18n) has some registered (sorry, I don't use any so I can't advise you which is the best)
- Use a properties-editor tool ([search on google](https://www.google.es/webhp?q=properties%20editor%20i18n%20java))
- Make it by hand:

  1. Copy `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application.properties` to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application_ar.properties`
  2. Modify `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/application_ar.properties` with translation
  3. Scape string to *unicode java codes*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18978720/2295657) explains how do it using JDK tools

After file is created you don't have to do anything to configure: *Spring WMC* locates the file with language sufix and use it.

Good luck!