# What happened to native2ascii executable in Java 9

Tags: java-9

I am trying to compile my application with java 9 and it is failing because
native2ascii executable is not there.  Has it been removed in Java 9?  Is there another tool that does the same thing?

Comment: What build tool are you using and what is the error? The comments from the bug report imply that it will be broken for versions of Ant less than 1.9.8.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, native2ascii was removed in Java 9. From [the bug report to remove it](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074431), "JEP 226 proposes to support UTF Properties file that will address the original motivation of creating the native2ascii tool." For more information visit [JEP 226](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/226).

Comment: This does not work. `new Properties().load(inputStream)` still does not treat `inputStream` as UTF-8 in Java 17 and corrupts unicode characters. It seems that this JEP talks about Resource Bundles which are not the same as Properties.