# Convert english to Arabic unicode format

Tags: java

Can anyone help to identify what is the below Unicode format? I am trying to convert my English text to Unicode in the below format only so that I can use the same in my java project.

\u0623\u0646\u062a \u0645\u0634\u062a\u0631\u0643 \u0639\u0628\u0631 \u0631\u0642\u0645

The above format is working fine, but I don't have the website details from where the same was done.

Comment: What do you mean "what is the below unicode format"?

Comment: It's `\u` plus 4 hexadecimal digits denoting its corresponding Unicode *code point*.

Comment: For example `\u0623` is ᕱ. 0x0623 = 1571, and Unicode code point 1571 = ᕱ.

Comment: ```yourString.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.printf("\\u%04X", c));```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear but if you just want to convert clear text into unicode sequences here is how you can do that:

There is an Open Source java library MgntUtils that has a Utility that converts Strings to unicode sequence and vise versa:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Above is a copy of my answer for [Convert International String to \u Codes in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java/53946044#53946044)

**Disclaimer**: The library is written and maintained by me