# How to convert utf8 string to escape string in JSON Java?

Tags: java, json, string, utf-8, unicode-escapes

I want to convert a UTF-8 string to escape \uXXX format in value of JSON Object.

I used both JSON Object and Gson, but did not work for me in this case:

```
JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
js.put("lastReason","nguyễn");
System.out.println(js.toString());
```

and

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String new_js = gson.toJson(js.toString());
System.out.println(new_js);
```

**Output: {"test":"nguyễn"}**

But i am expect that my result is:

**Expected Output: {"test":"nguy\u1EC5n"}**

Any solutions for this case, please help me to resolve it.

Comment: It depends from what lib do you use `JSONObject `, the problem is in `js.toString()` method. could you add a full package name for `JSONObject`?

Comment: You can modify the string before adding it to the json map. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230190/convert-international-string-to-u-codes-in-java

Comment: Surely then you'd want to do `js.put("lastReason","nguy\\u1EC5n");`?

Comment: @g00se sure, i need to sync up all string with escape unicode.

Comment: @SimGel if there is not any solution, i must loop all key in JSON and subkey contains JSON to escape them.

Comment: @Rustam I added JSONObject package (org.json.JSONObject), but it does'nt do escapse string.

Comment: If you want to encode the string during seralization another option would be to use `Jackson` with a custom serializer: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: @SimGel thanks, i want to a way to dump json to string similar with json.dumps() in Python. In Python, when I used ```json.dumps(json_var)``` , json string is encoded automatically. For Java, are there any solution for that problem?

Comment: Why, btw, do you need this escaped form?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [apache commons-text](https://github.com/apache/commons-text) library to change a string to use Unicode escape sequences. Use `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils` to translate the text before adding it to `JSONObject`.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("nguyễn")
```

will produce

```
nguy\u1EC5n
```

One possible problem with using `StringEscapeUtils` might be that it will escape control characters as well. If there is a tab character at the end of the string it will be translated to `\t`. I.e.:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("nguyễn\t")
```

will produce an incorrect string:

```
nguy\u1EC5n\t
```

You can use `org.apache.commons.text.translate.UnicodeEscaper` to get around this but it will translate every character in the string to a Unicode escape sequence. I.e.:

```
UnicodeEscaper ue = new UnicodeEscaper();
ue.translate(rawString);
```

will produce

```
\u006E\u0067\u0075\u0079\u1EC5\u006E

or 

\u006E\u0067\u0075\u0079\u1EC5\u006E\u0009
```

Whether it is a problem or not is up to you to decide.

Comment: thank you so much, so only way translate text before putting ```JSONObject```.

Comment: Note that there is also the method [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJson(java.lang.String)) where _"The only difference between Java strings and Json strings is that in Json, forward-slash (/) is escaped"_. A minor point, but using `escapeJson()` instead of `escapeJava()` might make a bit more sense for the OP's use case, if only for clarity.