# How to show Persian or Arabic alphabet wordpress post in Android application?

Tags: java, android, localization

I have a Persian wordpress site, now I want to get its data in the JSON format and shown on a android application, how can I do it with the Persian language?

> SITE_URL/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/

**or**

> SITE_URL/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=1

I've used these 2 methods but none of them work, and the news part in the application is empty but the category is shown!

```
public interface ApiService {
          String BaseURL= "https://irantopbet.net/";

          /*category() used for fetch main category list*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100")
          Call<JsonElement> category();

          /*getFeatureNews() used for featuresnews list*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
          Call<JsonElement> getFeatureNews();

          /*contactus used for add contact details */
          @FormUrlEncoded
          @POST("api/contact_us.php")
          Call<JsonElement> contactus(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("message") String message);

          /*getNewsByCatID used for fetch news using category id*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts?")
          Call<JsonElement> getNewsByCatID(@Query("categories") String catID);

          /*search used for search all project content*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?")
          Call<JsonElement> search(@Query("search") String world);

          /*getNewsByNewsID used for get news detais*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{NewsId}")
          Call<JsonElement> getNewsByNewsID(@Path("NewsId") String newsID);

          /*getAllComment used for view all comments*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/comments")
          Call<JsonElement> getAllComment(@Query("post") String postId);

          /*addComment used for add comment in news details*/
          @FormUrlEncoded
          @POST("api/comment.php")
          Call<JsonElement> addComment(@Field("post_id") String postId,
                                       @Field("comment_author") String commentAuthor,
                                       @Field("comment_author_email") String commentAuthorEmail,
                                       @Field("comment_content") String commentContent,
                                       @Field("user_id") String userId);

          /*getAllLatestNews used for all latest news list*/
          @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts?")
          Call<JsonElement> getAllLatestNews(@Query("categories") String 
          catID,@Query("page") int per_page);
}
```

https://irantopbet.net/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=100
this works and the category is shown in the application

But
https://irantopbet.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
when opening this link there is something on it but nothing is shown in the application

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are already receiving unicode character from server. That means you will have to transform those unicode characters to Persian characters. Please follow this answer: [How to conver unicode into text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499824/how-to-convert-unicode-string-into-text-in-android/33500275)