# AWS lambda returning code as the result of OCR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-tesseract

I have imported Pytesseract layers to Lambda console in AWS.And also used it but whenever the tesseract ocr detect languages other than english it return some kind of code like this

```
{"statusCode": 200, "body": "\"\\u09ad\\u09bf\\u09a7\\u09cd\\u09be\\u09ac\\u09c1\\u09af\\u09bc\\u09c7\\u09b\\u09a4\\u09be\\u09b0\\u0995\\u09be ""}
```

I have linked all the code below.Can some one explain me what is going wrong here.It was a bengali image I supplied to the OCR.And it gives me the above result.

```
import json
import base64
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import pytesseract


def ocr(img):
  custom_config = r'-l eng+equ+ben --psm 6'
  ocr_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config)
  return ocr_text

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
  body_image64 = "Base 64 Image"

  # Decode & save image to /tmp
  with open("/tmp/saved_img.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(body_image64))
    
    # # Read the image with cv2
    # image = cv2.imread("/tmp/saved_img.png")
    # # Convert to grayscale
    #  gr_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   
  # open image
  im = Image.open("/tmp/saved_img.png")
  # preprocessing
  gr_image = im.convert('L')# grayscale
  gr_image = gr_image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter()) 
   
  # Ocr
  ocr_text = ocr(gr_image)
 
  print(im)
  # TODO implement
  return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(ocr_text)
  }
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but you might also want to consider using AWS Textract instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499824/how-to-convert-unicode-string-into-text-in-android) to convert the unicode characters at client side,