# How do I print escape characters in Java?

Tags: java

When I have a string such as:

```
String x = "hello\nworld";
```

How do I get Java to print the actual escape character (and not interpret it as an escape character) when using `System.out`?

For example, when calling

```
System.out.print(x);
```

I would like to see:

```
hello\nworld
```

And not:

```
hello
world
```

I would like to see the actual escape characters for debugging purposes.

Comment: \ is called backslash. Escape character means something else

Comment: @user2587965 — An [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in computing is "a character that invokes an alternative interpretation on the following characters in a character sequence."  In a Java string, the backslash is an escape character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
public static String unEscapeString(String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        switch (s.charAt(i)){
            case '\n': sb.append("\\n"); break;
            case '\t': sb.append("\\t"); break;
            // ... rest of escape characters
            default: sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and you run `System.out.print(unEscapeString(x))`.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, but I didn't know I'd have to write a function that does this. This means knowing about all possible escape characters. I figured there was a library that already does this.

Comment: There is, I think, but I haven't used it. There's another Stack Overflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java) on this.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a similar question but just couldn't get the keywords right :)

Answer (score 38):

Use the method "StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava" in Java lib "org.apache.commons.lang"

```
String x = "hello\nworld";
System.out.print(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(x));
```

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava in "org.apache.commons.lang" is Deprecated
as of version 3.6, use commons-text StringEscapeUtils instead

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the slash itself:

```
String x = "hello\\nworld";
```

Comment: The limitation here is what if another user was using the program but did not know this tip?

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println("hello \\nworld");`

Answer (score 1):

Java has its escape-sequence just the same as that in C.
use `String x = "hello\\nworld";`

Comment: see here for a reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the escape character.

```
String x = "hello\\nworld";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the backslash like `\\n`

Answer (score 0):

The following code produces octal escape sequences.  Modify the replacement function to produce what you need.

```
Pattern
 .compile ("[^\\p{Graph}]")
 .matcher ("A\tB\nC")
 .replaceAll
 (
   (final MatchResult r)
   -> String .format ("\\\\%03o", + r .group () .charAt (0)))
```

Another possibility would be to use `String .format ("^%c", r .group () .charAt (0) + '@')`—but it will only handle control characters.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). Although this may do more than you intend. Alternatively, use String replace methods for new lines, carriage returns and tab characters. Do keep in mind that there are also such things as unicode and hex sequences.

Comment: Regex quoting will not provide the correct answer in this case. First, this method is likely to just wrap the input with `\Q` and `\E`. Second, even if it did escape each character, the values don't match at all. For instance, the tab character `\t` is a valid regex character and would not need escaping, while `.` would need escaping.