# Print escaped representation of a String

Tags: java

How do I print the escaped representation of a string, for example if I have:

```
s = "String:\tA"
```

I wish to output:

```
String:\tA
```

on the screen instead of

```
String:    A
```

Comment: The internal representation has a tab character. It doesn't have a backslash and a t. What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Say I get a string from somewhere. I want to know exactly what it contains. I want to see "String:\tA" rather than "String:    A"

Comment: @Baz: Sure. But I just want to make sure that you understand that "\t" is just the Java source code representation. Your question talks about the "internal representation" - it's just a tab character.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7888004/873282

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print escape characters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888004/how-do-i-print-escape-characters-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
String xy = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(yourString);
System.out.println(xy);
```

from [Apache Commons Lang v2.6](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String))

deprecated in Apache Commons Lang v3.5+, use [Apache Commons Text v1.2](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-)

Comment: This is an old Q&A but its very useful especially for test generation. The updated link is https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/ and the package is now commons.lang3.... , that is use: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(yourString);

Answer (score 3):

For a given String you'll have to replace the control characters (like tab):

```
System.out.println("String:\tA\n".replace("\t", "\\t").replace("\n","\\n");
```

(and for the others too)

Answer (score 3):

Well strictly speaking the internal representation is an unsigned 16-bit integer. I think what you mean is that you want to escape the string.

There's a class called [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) in the Apache library to help with that.

```
String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\t");
System.out.println(escaped); // prints \t
```

Comment: Fixed the link. For future reference, googling "StringEscapeUtils apache" will easily find the documentation.