# How to get the real value of a variable including escape sequences in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, variables, escaping

I am parsing from an xml document into an array.
In my xml doc there are some line breaks notated in this format:

```
&#13;
```

My Eclipse console shows them correctly with a line break if i sysout the arraylist. 
But is it somehow possible to show what is really saved in that variable?

Example:

```
sysout(myarray[1]);
```

current output:

```
xyz

xyz
```

wanted output:(or something like that)

```
xyz\n\nxyz
```

Comment: the current output _is_ what is really saved in the variable.  if you want to escape certain characters for display, that is a different story, entirely unrelated to xml.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print escaped representation of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701672/print-escaped-representation-of-a-string)

Comment: The answer you are looking for has already been posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888004/how-do-i-print-escape-characters-in-java

Comment: Look at `StringEscapeUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29), it has methods to (un)escape Java, XML and many more.

Comment: @stevenackley: But the accepted answer is not nice at all. Rater use `StringEscapeUtils`

Comment: I would have said the value without the escape sequences is the real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `escapeJava` at `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` from the [Apache Commons Lang library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). Take a look at the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). Download the library [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string.replace("\n", "\\n");
```