# Java Regex to Match Blank Line

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a sequence of unpredictable text from the middle of a formatted string. Here is a an example of what my string might look like:

> THIS PART NEVER CHANGES
> Payload
> UppErAndLowerCaseLetters
>   andDigitsNotPredictable
> ButDoesIncludeLineBreaks
>   OtherStuffThatIDon'tWant

Note that there are line breaks here that must be preserved. In this example, I want to capture in a String variable this text:

> Payload
> UppErAndLowerCaseLetters
>   andDigitsNotPredictable
>  ButDoesIncludeLineBreaks

So, my "delimiters" are the header part `THIS PART NEVER CHANGES` at the beginning and the double line break at the end. That's the tricky part. How do I write my regular expression to identify a double line break, but exclude a single line break? Here is what I have:

```
String payload = "THIS PART NEVER CHANGES" + 
        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
        "(.+?)" + 
        System.getProperty("line.separator") +
        System.getProperty("line.separator");

BufferedFileReader bfr = new BufferedFileReader();
String file_contents = bfr.readFileToString(myFile);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(payload);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file_contents);

while (matcher.find()) 
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

This almost works. If I take out the last `System.getProperty("line.separator")` from the payload string, I get the *first* line from the payload. When I leave it in, I get nothing.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `DOTALL` flag to match the newline characters

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(payload, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: That worked. I'll accept as soon as SO let's me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The regex

```
(?m:^(?=[\r\n]|\z))
```

will match a blank line because `m` causes `^` to match at the beginning of the line instead of the beginning of input, and `(?=[\r\n]|\z)` looks ahead to a newline or end of input.

As to the root cause of your problem, Reimeus is right about DOTALL.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a specific quantifier for your line break?

For instance:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\n{2,}");
String line = "\n\n";
System.out.println(p.matcher(line).find());
```

**Output**

```
true
```

If you want to use the escaped representation of your system line separator (instead of manually add the escaped `String`, whether `\n` or `\r\n`, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701672/print-escaped-representation-of-a-string) SO thread.