# How to print "\123" as "\123" in Java

Tags: java, escaping

I am getting a string as "\123" from input and since \ with number is a valid syntax, java is converting it to ASCII. But I want to treat it as "\123". I was trying to search for raw strings as python but could not find anything. Also tried to check escape-utils but it is also not giving the expected output.

Any pointers to resolve the issue are appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why would the escaping rules for *source code* matter when your string is coming from *user input*?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. This works perfectly fine: `class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { var s = System.console().readLine(); System.out.println(s); }}`.

Comment: You would have to go through the string and check for escape characters and append \ or use escapeutils.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888004/how-do-i-print-escape-characters-in-java has an excellent example on how to do it.

Comment: Can you share your code and Input?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape it. Try printing `"\\123"`