# Mocha fails with no string diff, utf-8?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a failing mocha test that outputs my string with the "Actual" and "Expected" highlighting... except that nothing's highlighted.

[image: no highlighting]

After some head-bashing, I think I've determined that my actual string contains some whacky UTF-8 characters that are completely hidden from me, and Mocha doesn't seem to know to highlight them.

I figured this out by writing out my expected and actual values to raw text files and loading them up in [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/), which shows that they differ by highlighting what appears to be empty spaces between words.

[image]

I tried loading the `utf8` library (on npm) and encoding one of the strings with `utf8.encode str`, and that still failed, but now the characters appear as something more than blank spaces, and Mocha does highlighting:

[image: some highlighting]

But either way, my tests are failing. How can I encode/decode/whatever these strings so that they match and my tests pass?

Btw, the comparison string I'm using in my test looks like this:

[image: comparison string]

Comment: How did you get the contents of the expected body? If you copy/pasted it then you probably need to convert the utf8 chars that you pasted into proper string literal utf8 format like `\u0065` or something.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I did copy/paste that... is there something I can put the string through that will convert these characters to string literals?

Comment: Since you pasted it into your text editor, what editor do you use? Maybe it saved your JS file as the incorrect encoding? Try running `file -bi filename.js` on your mocha file and make sure it us utf-8. Just copy-pasting should be fine since UTF8 charaters inside a string literal should be fine.

Comment: It looks like your console font can't display the particular characters involved; you might try setting it to use a more comprehensive font (how to do this depends on your OS/desktop).

Comment: I use Vim through iTerm2 (not MacVim), so I had copy/pasted it directly into a Vim buffer. I checked the filetype of my spec and it looks to be set correctly: `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. I'd love to know how to convert this copy/pasted text into escaped literals--how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that either your text editor is saving your source code as proper UTF-8, or convert those copy/pasted chars to escaped literals as @loganfsmyth correctly comments.

Comment: I've tried copy/pasting with several editors I know support UTF-8 (TextMate, SublimeText2), and I've checked the file type with `file -bi` and the charset is set correctly to `text/plain; charset=utf-8`. I think my best bet would be to convert all the chars to escaped literals, as you suggest, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you are confident the binary data on disk is properly encoded UTF-8, open it with a hex editor (or tell your editor to open it as hex), then convert the hex to unicode escaped literals. This answer has an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8005329/266795

Comment: That seems like a lot of work... is there anyway I can pass this text through some program and have it filter offending characters to literals while leaving the rest of the string intact? I got my test passing by changing my expectation to `it "gets the full body", -> escape(@parsed.body).should.equal escape(page.body)`, but now my diff is a massive block of escaped characters, which makes it really hard to have a nice visual diff during TDD...

Comment: Sure, if you write "some program" to do that. :-) In JavaScript you can use String.charCodeAt and just ignore anything higher than ASCII (127).