# How can I convert UTF-8 literals, into its UTF-8 character?

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a bunch of text files that were encoded in `UTF-8`. The text inside the files look like this: `\x6c\x69b/\x62\x2f\x6d\x69nd/m\x61x\x2e\x70h\x70`.

I've copied all these text files and placed them into a directory `/convert/`.

I need to read each file and convert the encoded literals into characters, then save the file. `filename.converted.txt`

What would be the smartest approach to do this? What can I do to convert to the new text? Is there a function for handling Unicode text to convert between the literal to character types? Should I be using a different programming language for this?

This is what I have at the moment:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class decode {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File directory = new File("C:/convert/");
        String[] files = directory.list();
        boolean success = false;
        for (String file : files) {
            System.out.println("Processing \"" + file + "\"");

            //TODO read each file and convert them into characters
            success = true;

            if (success) {
                System.out.println("Successfully converted \"" + file + "\"");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to convert \"" + file + "\"");
            }

            //save file
            if (success) {
                try {
                    FileWriter open = new FileWriter("C:/convert/" + file + ".converted.txt");
                    BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(open);
                    write.write("TODO: write converted text into file");
                    write.close();
                    System.out.println("Successfully saved \"" + file + "\" conversion.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was link I provided in your previous post useless? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Comment: @svaor I made a new question to cover what I was trying to accomplish. The link was not useless it was helpful but I needed more insight to get started. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(It looks like there's some confusion about what you mean - this answer assumes the input file is entirely in ASCII, and uses "\x" to hex-encode any bytes which aren't in the ASCII range.)

It sounds to me like the UTF-8 part of it is actually irrelevant. You can treat it as opaque binary data for output. Assuming the input file is entirely ASCII:

- Open the input file as text (e.g. using `FileInputStream` wrapped in `InputStreamReader` specifying an encoding of "US-ASCII")
- Open the output file as binary (e.g. using `FileOutputStream`)
- Read each character from the input
- Is it '\'?

  - If not, write the character's ASCII value to the output stream (just case from `char` to `byte`)
  - What's the next character?
  - If it's 'x', read the next two characters, convert them from hex to a byte (there's lots of code around to do this part), and write that byte to the output stream
  - If it's '\', write the ASCII value for '\' to the output stream
  - Otherwise, possibly throw an exception indicating failure
- Loop until you've exhausted the input file
- Close both files in finally blocks

You'll then have a "normal" UTF-8 file which should be readable by any text editor which supports UTF-8.

Comment: Some of the files contain php functions in plaintext but my ultimate goal is to restore the files into plaintext. My friend "obfuscated" these files and I was trying to show him how pointless it was.

Answer (score 0):

[java.io.InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) can be used to convert an input stream from an arbitrary charset into Java `char`s.  I'm not exactly sure how you want to write it back out, though.  Do you want non-ASCII characters to be written out as ASCII Unicode escape sequences?

Comment: It sounds like we've understood the question in very different ways... it'll be interesting to see what the correct interpretation is.