# Loading break line sign "\n" from file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I need to load from text file text which I will be replacing in other string.
For example I have text file:

```
\n;(br)
```

After loading this file I need to change all break lines to `(br)` so I will receive one line string. 
Problems is when I'm loading text from file - I don't get string `\n;(br)` but `\\n;(br)`

Anyone know how to do that?

My code - I know that I'm adding '\n' in method applyFilters but it is because that there can be situation when I don't whant to change that.

```
    void loadSource(){

    File file = new File(sourcePath);
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    String text;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));         
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    try{
        while((text = reader.readLine()) != null){
            sourceText.add(text);               
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}

void loadFilters(){

    File file = new File(filterPath);
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    String text;

    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));         
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Błąd, brak pliku źródłowego");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        while((text = reader.readLine()) != null){
            filterText.add(text);               
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}

void applyFilters(){

    for (String s : sourceText){
        finalText = finalText+ s + "\n";            
    }
    for(String filter : filterText)
    {           
        finalText = finalText.replace(filter.split(";")[0],filter.split(";")[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(finalText);

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us what you're working with so that we can help you.

Comment: You could post some code, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the "\n" in your text file to represent a newline character rather than a backslash followed by an n. Have a look at this question:

[How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)