# Add new line `\n' on TextView won't work

Tags: android, textview, newline

I don't know why it doens't work. My `TextView` already set lines=6. String is set in code, like this :

```
address.setText((String) bundle.get("address"));
```

Above code still display `\n` as String not new line. `bundle.get("address")` is retrieved from `.dat` which is "line1\nline2" file store in `asset`  But when i try this :

```
address.setText("line1\nline2");
```

this code works fine.

Any idea what gone wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to show your code reading the .dat file too.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the reading file, It shows the content, but won't display `\n` as new line, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really an answer i'm looking for, but i managed to do a bit of code to replace `\n` inside `String` (read from text file) to `\n` in code. here's my solution.

```
String seperator = "\n";  
String []tempText = a.split(seperator);

if (a.contains(seperator)){
        String b= "";
        for (String c : tempText)
            b +=c+"\n";
        b= b.substring(0, b.length()-2);
        address.setText(b);

    }else{
        address.setText((String) bundle.get("address"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try giving an escape sequence for the .
Please replace \n with \\n in the asset file, and see if it shows rightly now?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the slash encoded in your .dat file. Make sure that it's actually a newline character there.

Comment: I'm not quite understand what you mean. it displays : `line1\nline2` but display as it is, no separator line

Comment: What I mean is that if in your .dat file you have literally: line1\nline2, then that's what will come out (a slash then an n). \n is a special convention in Java (and some other languages) to represent a newline character. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java) for more.