# Replace an escaped escape sequence with its unescaped value

Tags: java, regex

As input I get the string `"some text\\nsome text"` -> so shown as `"some text\nsome text"`.
How is it possible to delete one backslash and get 
`"some text\nsome text"` -> shown as

```
"some text
some text"
```

That will work also for other special characters like `"\t"`?
With regex it's possible to do only like
    `textLine.replace("\\n", "\n") and so on.`

Is there another way?

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\");

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not doing what the OP asks for.

Comment: @Lex you don't want to "remove one backslash", you want to "replace an escaped escape sequence with it's unescaped value".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Comment: @Romain, I commented before the edit, then it did answer the question :)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need reinvent the wheel. You can use [**`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils`**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) for unescape Java strings. Unescapes any Java literals found in the String. For example, it will turn a sequence of '`\`' and '`n`' into a newline character, unless the '`\`' is preceded by another '`\`'. In that case, you need unescape one more time.

**Code**:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava;

public class Unescape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("some text\\nsome text");
        System.out.println(unescapeJava("some text\\nsome text"));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
some text\nsome text
some text
some text
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you playing with multiple line regex?
Then you can compile a regex:

```
Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+).*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/multiline.shtml

Answer (score 0):

So it's not so obvious, you want to create one char from two chars.

I made this method :

```
    String res="";
    boolean backslash=false;
    for(char c : "some text\\nsome text".toCharArray()){
        if(c!='\\'){
            if(backslash){
                switch(c){
                    case 'n' :
                        res+='\n';
                        break;
                    case 't' :
                        res+='\t';
                        break;

                }
                backslash=false;
            }else{
                res+=c;
            }
        }
        else{
            backslash=true;
        }
    }
```

Maybe it will help you, it actually works only for the case I put in switch (EOL and Tab).

NB: Replace String with StringBuilder if you want better performance.