# Whitespace char sequence to Whitespace

Tags: java, whitespace

I'm searching for a solution to convert char sequences like '\''n' to '\n' without writing a switch for all possible whitespace commands like ('\t', '\r', '\n', etc.)

Is there something build in or a clever trick to do that?

Comment: You could use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Comment: Difficult to fully understand the question. Can you provide some input and expected output please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Comment: McDowell +1 - Works perfect! @anubhava, see aioobes example. He nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, once compiled, `"\\n"` has nothing to do with `"\n"` afaik. I would suggest doing something as follows:

**Pure Java:**

```
String input = "\\n hello \\t world \\r";

String from = "ntrf";
String to   = "\n\t\r\f";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\\\(["+from+"])").matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find())
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "" + to.charAt(from.indexOf(m.group(1))));
m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Using Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils:**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

...

System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(input));
```