# Convert any String to UTF-8 format

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I have this below String, I don't know it is in which format honestly?

```
Under%20\302\243100%2E00
```

And I need to convert the above String in `UTF-8 format` and the output should be like below for above String.

```
Under%20Â£100%2E00
```

So Basically How can I convert any String to UTF-8 format in Java?

Comment: That's UTF-8 data partially URL-encoded and then decoded as Latin-1. It results in "Under £100.00" when fully decoded.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to encode the decimal point (`'.'`) as `"%2E"` in the final string.  It is not necessary if this string is intended to be part of a URL, HTML, XML, JSON ... or anything else that immediately springs to mind.

Answer (score 2):

What you have in that character sequence (which is not a Java string literal) is a mixture of two encodings: octal encoding and url encoding.  Octal encoding looks like \xxx where xxx is a character code in octal.  [Url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) looks like %XX where XX is a character code in hex.  [Octal encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.6) is actually part of the Java specification.  Now, converting octal into a Java string isn't trivial.  There is no built-in method for that.  Look at this thread, though, for ideas on how to do it: [How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java).

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is not a Java string literal ... so the "ideas" in the linked article do not carry over automatically.

Comment: you're right, I should make it more explicit that the above is not a string literal.

Comment: So is there any way I can convert the above String in UTF-8 format? Or some Java functions?