# Removing non printable characters

Tags: java

I have a column in database which contains non printable characters;

```
String xyz = "Company Name\r\n Magna";
```

Once retrieved from database, in java, the values is shown as below

```
String companyname = "Company Name\\r\\n Magna";"
```

It adds an addtional escape character. How can i remove the non printable characters now ?

```
companyname.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", ""); // Doesn't work.
```

Even if i use `StringBuffer`, it won't work because of additional escape character.

Please advice.

Comment: you don't have non-printable characters in your database, what you have is encoded character escapes in your database.  you'll have to replace the escape strings directly.

Comment: question is not clear. Do you have escape characters in the DB, or actually do you have plain ASCII letter which include backlashes (and which you want to interpret as escape characters?

Comment: @leonbloy - i'm pretty sure it's the latter.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java

Comment: I just wonder why you would write your application to store text in the database in that form in the first place ....

Comment: well some job inserted the non printable characters in the database, I am trying to recreate that scenario to add a fix to the code, hope that explains.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have created a problem for yourself by the way that you have encoded the data before you put it into the database.

In the first instance, a `replaceAll` that replaces character sequences `'\' 'r'` and `'\' 'n'` is required; e.g.

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\\r|\\\\n", "");
```

Note that in order to match the literal backslash characters they have to be escaped **twice**.  One time for the string literal, and a second time because backslash is a metacharacter in regexes.

But, IMO, a better fix for this is to not encode CR and NL characters that way in your database.  Can't you just represent them in the database without escaping?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I can't do that, our application doesn't own the database. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, in that case I hope that the replaceAll approach works for you then.

Answer (score 0):

How about good old replace :

```
String text = readfromDatabase();
text = text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```

or

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

or

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\r", "").replaceAll("\\n", "");
```