# How to force escaping of characters in java

Tags: java, string, escaping

I have a string with escape characters in such a way that the when the string is printed it results in another string with valid escape characters. How do i retrieve that string which looks like the one when the first string is printed?

Here's the code - the initial string looks as such:

```
String string = "{\"agent\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"James Bond\\\"}\"}";
System.out.println("str: "+string);
```

Executing the code would produce

```
str: {"agent":"{\"name\":\"James Bond\"}"}
```

I was to get the string as it appears in the output.

Comment: How *does* this String appear in the output? Why `\\\"name\\\"` instead of `\"name\"`?

Comment: well i guess u can simply replace all " and \ with \" and \\. To do so use string.replace

Comment: How would you like the String to be printed? Can you give an example?

Comment: Why are you attempting to write/parse json manually?  There are a ton of libraries for that.

Comment: The second block of code shows how the string appears in the output. I was working with JSONs when I came across this problem.

Comment: @chai.nadig: So far everything seems to be as you have specified. How would you like the output to be _different_ from the correct output you have shown? **What is your actual problem?**

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't want a different output. I want the escaping of characters to be done so that I get a string which looks like the one in the output.

Comment: @chai.nadig - this can only be answered properly if you state **clearly** what kind of escaping you want.  Is it Java String literal escaping?  Is it JSON escaping?  Is it something else?

Comment: @chai.nadig: If you're already getting the output you want, then what's your problem? It would seem then that you _already_ have the escaping you want in order to get the output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `String unescapeJava(String)` method of `StringEscapeUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

example:

```
String in = "a\\tb\\n\\\"c\\\"";

System.out.println(in);
//This prints
// a\tb\n\"c\"

String out = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(in);

System.out.println(out);
//This prints
// a    b
// "c"
```

You can see more on [How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

i guess u are looking for that

```
String a="\"agent\":\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"James Bond\\\"}q\"";

a=a.replace("\\", "\\\\");
a=a.replace("\"","\\\"");
```