# cannot convert Json string to JSONObject or JSONArray

Tags: java, c#, android, json, wcf

i have created a rest wcf web service and hosted in local iis, the json string is converted with JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object) of Newtonsoft package.

the output of the web service is

```
"[{\"companyId\":2,\"companyName\":\"A\"},
{\"companyId\":8,\"companyName\":\"B\"}]"
```

this web service is consume by android apps, 
i tried with JSONArray and JSONObject but it keep on throwing exception

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 2 of   
[{\"companyId\":2,\"companyName\":\"A\"},{\"companyId\":8,\"companyName\":\"B\"}]
org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 2 of 
"[{\"companyId\":2,\"companyName\":\"A\"},    
{\"companyId\":8,\"companyName\":\"B\"}]"
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"companyId":2,"companyName":"A"},
{"companyId":8,"companyName":"B"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be 
converted to JSONArray
```

this is the code in android class

```
public JSONArray RequestWebService(URL urlToRequest) {
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(RETRIEVE_TIMEOUT);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream());
            String result = getResponseText(in);
            //result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
            //result = result.replace("/\\/g", "");
            JSONArray j = new JSONArray(result);
            return j
        }
    return null;
}

private String getResponseText(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    try{
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }finally {
        if (rd != null) {
            rd.close();
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: share the complete stack trace

Comment: Share your code how you tried to consume this json and show us the error message.

Comment: Hope using current json String after removing `\` ?

Comment: Remove ``\`` symbol before you convert it.

Comment: All those backslashes: are they an artifact of your development environment (e.g. the Visual Studio debugger displays it like this) or are they really part of the transmitted data? If the latter is the case, then that's the problem.

Comment: how can i remove \ symbol

Comment: i just pass the List<object> to the JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object), possible it generate / for each list item

Comment: It seems that you have a double encoding: first you encode the data as JSON and then its encoded again somehow where the backslashes are inserted. Remove that second encoding, i.e. prevent the backslashes from being generated in the first place.

Comment: try use ``sb.append(line + "\n");`` instead of  ``sb.append(line);`` , it will make you json string clearly.

Comment: I have converted your json String after some modification, its working here is json String : [
  {
    "companyId": 2,
    "companyName": "A"
  },
  {
    "companyId": 8,
    "companyName": "B"
  }
]

Comment: so it is the problem of \?

Comment: i tried to valid the json, some json web site is valid, and then i found that for RFC 7159 standard it is valid

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/15476670/1520438

Comment: @DanhDC the link is helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = "Your Response";
try{    
    JsonArray jAry = new JsonArray(response);
        JsonObjct jObj;

        for(int i=0;i<jAry.length;i++){
            jObj = JAry.getJsonObject(i);

  // You can get your string from object jobj and also use it by store it value in arraylist.
        }
  } catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: when i put my response in JSONArray, it throw an exception

Comment: Please use try-catch block when you parse json array.

Comment: ya, then the string will be null

Comment: If you want to get "companyId than simply you can get by jsonobj 
i.e jObj.optString("companyId ");

Comment: you don get what i mean lol, i cant even parse my response to jsonarray now.

Comment: put here your response which you get in string.

Comment: "[{\"companyId\":2,\"companyName\":\"A\"},
{\"companyId\":8,\"companyName\":\"B\"}]"

Comment: Remove \ symbol before you convert it from your webservice response