# Remove added escape character in my json string

Tags: java, android, json

I have an application that gets data(json) from my webservice(rest). I can successfully
get my json. What i did is this:

```
            try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            inStream = httpEntity.getContent(); 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            inStream.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logs...
        }

        // and so on...
```

But when i try to print my `json (String)`, since I have a url got from that json...
my url looks like this `something\/image\/myimage.png` insted of `something/image/myimage.png`
My problem where and how can i remove the additional "\"in my url. Is this an escape character?
Any ideas? It would be great if you share some. Though I'm currently also looking for a fix. But as of now, I can hardly find it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Use str.replaceALL("\\\\","") to remove the escape characters.

Comment: and now i wonder why nothing has changed.. it's because that's the way logcat displayed the trace...