# Java: how to convert UTF-8 (in literal) to unicode

Tags: java, encoding, encode, unicode-literals

I've a UTF-8(in literal) like this "\xE2\x80\x93."

I'm trying to convert this into Unicode using Java.

But I was not able to find a way to convert this.

Can anyone help me on this?

Regards,
Sat

Comment: You would have to parse the String into a `char[]` and then convert it into your desired `String`.

Comment: the [`byte[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])) constructor of String is the answer to your problem. If necessary, also provide the charset name.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you have as input. Something like `String input = "\xE2\x80\x93";`?

Comment: `"\xE2\x80\x93."` is not a valid string literal in Java. All string literals in Java are UTF-16. Can you be more explicit about where you are sourcing the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(new String(new byte[] {
    (byte)0xE2, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x93 }, "UTF-8"));
```

prints an em-dash, which is what those three bytes encode. It is not clear from your question whether you have such three bytes, or literally the string you have posted. If you have the string, then simply parse it into bytes beforehand, for example with the following:

```
final String[] bstrs = "\\xE2\\x80\\x93".split("\\\\x");
final byte[] bytes = new byte[bstrs.length-1];
for (int i = 1; i < bstrs.length; i++)
  bytes[i] = (byte) ((Integer.parseInt(bstrs[i], 16) << 24) >> 24);
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: The solution which Marko gave is working for me.Thanks Marko.

Comment: @Sat Do you know about *accepting* answers? That's what you should do on StackOverflow instead of leaving a descriptive comment. You just need to click on the checmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Why is there a `<< 24` followed by `>> 24` ?

Comment: @Beryllium It's about sign extension before descending into `byte`.

Comment: @Marko I've a string like this which contains that UTF-8 value."We celebrate the ideas \xE2\x80\x93"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Apache Commons Lang [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Or if you do know that the string will always be \xHH\xHH then you can:

```
String hex = input.replace("\x", "");
byte[] bytes = hexStringToByteArray(hex);
String result = new String(bytes, "utf-8");
```

`hexStringToByteArray` is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

Also see this other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java).

Comment: We are using hadoop hbase table to store the data and when data is stored into hbase table, it gets stored in this format \xE2\x80\x93. When we try to convert this into Unicode using StringEscapeUtils and some other utilities..nothing helped.

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion, to manually convert the \xHH to bytearray and then decode?

Comment: @Marko I've a string like this which contains that UTF-8 value.
"We celebrate the ideas \xE2\x80\x93". 
If my string contains "We celebrate the idea\xE2\x80\x93s", I use regex to replace this with 0x. So it will look like "We celebrate the idea0xE20x80x93s". Is there way to parse this data and get only the hexadecimal value?