# HTML labels are displayed with ascii characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I have html file and it has some labels.when i usually get the values through request parameters appended to URL. when i display the values in an html they will be dispalyed with ASCII chars as below. am getting values with %20 from my URL itself. And am reading them in servlet and forward to some.jsp

```
Name=Hellow%20how%20are%20you
```

But i want out put as:

```
Name=Hello how are you
```

Do i need to do anything in my html to render the value without ASCII ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `unescape()`:

```
Name = unescape("Hellow%20how%20are%20you"); // = "Hellow how are you"
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dS2k3/)

Comment: can i set any encoding in my servlet itself? while reading request parameters?

Comment: Did you meen Java instead of javascript ? check this to unescape strings in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java

Comment: can i do as request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); in servlet?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have servlet here , so you talk about java not javascript i guess.

Any way In java you got [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) to escape/unescape.

In Javascript you escape through [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), but I think the Commons component I gave to you will satisfy your needs.

Comment: will String queryString = URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8"); solve my problem?

Comment: i don't think so ,but try it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting :

```
URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: it's good that you have solved your problem and posted an answer but it would have been much nicer if you have explained how you got the above code so others can understand