# how to substitute the "\t" value available in a variable in java

Tags: java, string

I am having an `xml`

```
<field>
       <fieldSeparator>\t</fieldSparator>
       <fieldOrder>field1,field2,field3</fieldOrder>
</field>
```

corresponsing FieldVO has the respective values in it.

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append("someValue").append(fieldSeparator).append("SomeOtherText");
```

Output - `someValue\tSomeOtherText`

Here i want to render the tab space instead of `"\t"`.

But

```
String str = "text1,text2,text3";
String str1="\t";
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append(str.replaceAll(",",str1));
System.out.println(stringBuffer);
```

`Output --> text1    text2    text`3.

Can anybody explain those 2 behaviours?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an XML file is read, then `\t` is read as two separate characters. In Java it will look like this: `\\t`. Just replace it like:

```
str.replace("\\t", "\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your string at runtime (through a debugger).
It probably has `\\t` and not `\t`.
If so, the behavior is quite normal.
You should see what exactly you have in your string.
Then you should replace `\\t` with `\t`.

Comment: Just did that before seeing your reply.Thanks much for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\\t` instead of `\t`.