# How do I convert a unicode-string to a readable string

Tags: java, unicode-string

I have this string `"\U05d0\U05d5\U05d2\U05e0\U05d3\U05d4","\U05d0\U05d5\U05d6\U05d1\U05e7\U05d9\U05e1\U05d8\U05df","\U05d0\U05d5\U05e1\U05d8\U05e8\U05d9\U05d4"`

how do i convert it to a readable string? (note this is supposed to be hebrew)

i tried this method but it didnt work

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
String decoded = new String(bytes); 
System.out.println(decoded);
```

Comment: Not that straight forward. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java for hints.

Comment: **Never use `String.getBytes()` or `String(byte[])`.** They are machine-dependent, they use default system encoding and they often lead to data corruption.

Comment: @KarolS thanks :) however, since i needed a 1 time conversion, this was OK. However, I would like to know if there is a more universal approach to this problem, then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `U` should be lowercase `u`:

```
    String s = "\u05d0\u05d5\u05d2\u05e0\u05d3\u05d4";

    try{

        byte[] bytes   = s.getBytes();
        String decoded = new String(bytes); 

        System.out.println(decoded);

    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {      
        // ...  
    }
```

See [Byte Encodings and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html).

Output:

```
אוגנדה
```

Comment: This will horribly break on systems where the current character set isn't idempotent. A simple System.out.println(s) should work if the system character ser supports hebrew.

Comment: You are right. Basically you can get the character encoding and call `getBytes(getChararcterEncoding())` then this shouldn't be a problem anymore. I edited my answer.

Comment: sorry but without the getBytes part,  it does not work