# Print unicode literal string as Unicode character

Tags: java, unicode-string, unicode-escapes, unicode-literals

I need to print a unicode literal string as an equivalent unicode character.

```
System.out.println("\u00A5"); // prints  ¥

System.out.println("\\u"+"00A5"); //prints \u0045  I need to print it as ¥
```

How can evaluate this string a unicode character ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... The first option already prints what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess op wants to dynamically create Unicode during livetime.

Comment: What if someone wanted to just print "\u"? Are you *actually* looking for a string parser? You could always use Rhino's.

Comment: Have a look at answers to [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
System.out.println((char)(Integer.parseInt("00A5",16)));
```

probably works (haven't tested it)

Comment: If you want high code point support you can use a combination of this answer (for the integer parsing) and the answer of msandiford...

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the other options here, you could use:

```
int codepoint = 0x00A5; // Generate this however you want, maybe with Integer.parseInt
String s = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(codepoint));
```

This would have the advantage over other proposed techniques in that it would also work with Unicode codepoints outside of the basic multilingual plane.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a character.

```
System.out.println((char) 0x00A5);
```

This will of course not work for very high code points, those may require 2 "characters".