# How to set unicode in textview to show emoji in android?

Tags: android, textview, emoji

I am getting some Unicode string(emoji icons) from server in json string format.

My problem is strange and I am trying for last two days to resolve this issue. When I parse json and store all the Unicode string in an `ArrayList<String>` and try to set the text on TextView by getting value from the same ArrayList then it shows Unicode characters as :

Ghcghchgc`\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03fyju\ud83d\ude0c6\u20e3`

and when the same string I set on textview by passing static value as :
`textview.settext("Ghcghchgc\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03fyju\ud83d\ude0c6\u20e3")`

then the textview is showing perfect emojis.

I am stuck at this point. Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue or tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: try this new String("your text","UTF-8");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you want to [unescape your string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java) that you've got from JSON. If you don't mind adding a library, [Apache Commons has a String.unescapeJava](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String)) function which does what you need. If you don't want to add that library, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298836/400056).

Comment: i also use this but when i get respone again from server enojis become `?` symbol.

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya That means that your system does not have the proper Glyph for the symbol (i.e. the code point is not known) [read the description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me ( Kotlin version ):

`textView.text = String(Character.toChars(0x1F389))`