# Display \u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098 string to emoji in android textview?

Tags: android, textview

[image]

```
str = videoname.get(i);
    String toServer = str;
    String toServerUnicodeEncoded = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(toServer);
    viewHolder.textss.setText(toServerUnicodeEncoded);
    Log.e("emos",toServerUnicodeEncoded);
```

I am retrieving a string from URL using volley and the string contains emojis in it which I want to display in Android TextView. So for that, I have taken the string then passed it in `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(toServer)` and after that I am getting the emoji in `"\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098"` form, Instead of `"\uD83D\uDE18`" form . So how to display emoji in textview?

Comment: did you check this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-a-textview

Comment: Yes I did but my emoji is \u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098 like this

Comment: How can I convert it to unicode or \uD83D\uDE18 in this format???

Comment: Seems like prblem is at line no. 3 Check what is actual string & escapeJava() really doing the same or not https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: @PoojaPachchigar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137006/how-to-set-unicode-in-textview-to-show-emoji-in-android

Comment: @PoojaPachchigar have you checked that reference?

Comment: please also share your json reponse

Comment: Which @Vishal Thakkar

Comment: I have uploaded a pic in question @Adil

Comment: yes but please share JSON response in which you get emoji

Comment: \u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098New WhatsApp status\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u008D\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u008D

Comment: I am not getting full json response. I mean there are more than 1000 json objects so i am not getting all of them in Log

Comment: @PoojaPachchigar check my comments

Comment: @PoojaPachchigar https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String title = new String(c.getString("title").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

While Parsing the response I used this now instead of:

```
String title = String(c.getString("title");
```

This solved my emoji issue.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me , Try this.

Import this library

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

Then use its method to convert String(emoji code) to `Emoji` to show in `TextView`

```
textView.setText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(string_value));
```

> Eg:-

*Input String* :-
**"\ud83d\ude01"**

*Result*:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unescape` your escaped String.

You can use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) to unescape it.

The problem is fully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836).

Comment: If i'll unescape the escaped string then I am getting some square type images in the place of emojis

Comment: Are you sure your font supports Emojis? That might be the issue.

Comment: Yes I have used android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView

Comment: U mean I have to use typeface

Comment: Yes the default typeface might not support your emojis. You can use the Calliigraphy library for android for changing the typeface in the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to unicode directly use that string code like

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText("\u00F0");
```

for more unicide code check this [URL](https://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin)

Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: txt.setText("\u00F0");
This shows the exact string in textview

Comment: Yes in textview i am getting "ð" such image

Comment: But i am not getting the exact emoji

Comment: Is this an emoji ??

Comment: which emoji you want please share image in your question

Comment: I am retrieving the emoji from json using volley

Answer (score 0):

This is html encoding string. Check code:

```
String txt = "\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u0098";
tvHihiView.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt));
```

Comment: Didnt worked. Got something like this  "ð"  in textview

Comment: Can you provide origin data from server

Answer (score -1):

TextView txt_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_price);

txt_price.setText("\u20B9" + " 5000");