# Converting String characters to ASCII values

Tags: java, string, ascii

I have a program that reads from a file a set of characters and i need to transform this characters to their ascii representation.

En example of input is

```
'\n' '\0' 'a' 'b'
```

The input is comes from a file as a string and then is processed. To process the characters i use the getBytes() function from the string classand I don´t have any problem with regular characters ( `a`, `b`, ...), but with characters like `\n`  `getBytes` method returns two ASCII values (the value from `\` and the value from `n`).

How can I calculate the ASCII values of the whole string `\n`?

Comment: Does the input file contain a line *exactly* like it is in you question, including quotes and spaces?

Comment: Could you add the actual code?

Comment: This question looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java

Comment: Yes, another example : 

`print 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\n' ; `

Spaces and ; are skipped by the JFlex 

My actual code is the following

`char[] cs = char.toCharArray();
return cs[0];
`

Comment: And what if the characters are not in the ASCII set? E.g. `'ñ'`.

Comment: If the character is not in the ASCII set i will throw an exception because this program doesn´t accept non-ascii characters

Answer (score 2):

make use of charAt method to get the character and find ASCII value of that particular character .
beauty of charAt is it treats \n as single character .

```
int i;

    String sampleString="hello\nworld";
    for(i=0;i<sampleString.length();i++)
    System.out.println((int)sampleString.charAt(i));
```

Comment: Not working, this is the output

`Input is: '\n'
Value: \ `

I'm using charAt(1) to avoid the quote