# Converting javascript stringified string to java string

Tags: javascript, java, json, parse-platform, stringify

I have an app that uses Parse as a backend. Parse calls a web scraper which returns a string to Parse and I have to use stringify on the string I received because it's not always allowed to be sent over the network otherwise. Once I stringify that string how can I parse it in Java so that I have the original returned string. For instance, how do I go from this stringified string in javascript

```
"\"This is a string\"\r\n\t\t"
```

To this string in java

```
"This is a string"
```

To reiterate, I start with a String (such as "This is a string") but then have to stringify that to send it over the network (result "\"This is a string\"\r\n\t\t"). Once I return the stringified string to my android app, how can I get back the original string ("This is a string")?

Comment: See [Howto unescape a Java string literal in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `StringEscapeUtils` from apache commons

```
String input = "\"This is a string\"\r\n\t\t";

String output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(input);

System.out.println(output);

"This is a string"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I went ahead and used quite regex expression to take out escape characters. I didn't want to download a library that I would only need for one thing.