# Alternative representation for characters in REGEX

Tags: java, regex

Why am I not getting the same behavior when I build a Pattern from a literal regular expression and when I read the regular expression from a file?

```
String regex = "(?xi)(title)[\\.:;](.*) \043 Title property";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
System.out.println(pattern);
// will print:
```

> (?xi)(title)[.:;](.*) # Title property

This expression works yet when I attempt to read the regular expression from a file I encounter an issue. The '\043' isn't replaced to its proper form. Why so?

I'm trying to avoid the use of the literal '#' character symbol and thereby use and alternative representation of it because of other conflicts in my code.

Comment: The file contains `\043` literally? In source code, that's replaced by the compiler. You get no such behavior when you read it from wherever at runtime.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid #?

Comment: Then use `\u0023` if you do not want to use `#`. Please provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect you just do not have `#` in your input.

Comment: I had the wrong duplicate and I can't find a more relevant one. What you want to do is parse an _octal escape_ sequence from a file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's hidden somewhere in there. Up to you :)

Comment: the main idea is to build a small scanner, and to use a file representation like the Trivial Graph Format, wish is very basic an easy to understand, the problem is that '#' is use as a divider in the file specification to separate data from nodes and edges. So the use for representations like \u0023 en Unicode and \x043 en octal for that symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
 assertEquals(1, "\043".length());
 assertEquals("#", "\043");
```

... both pass.

That `\043` gets turned into one character ("#") by the Java compiler.

If you read a file containing:

```
\043
```

... into a String, then:

```
 assertEquals("\\043", stringFromFile);
```

... will pass. If you want a literal `\` in your string, you need to escape it with another `\`.