# Escaping characters in a string

Tags: java, escaping

I have a string that contains escaped characters:

```
String myString = "I\\nam\\na\\nmultiline\\nstring\\twith\\ttabs";
```

I would like to convert the escaped characters so that it would output:

```
System.out.println(myConvertedString);
```

```
I
am
a
multiline
string    with    tabs
```

Is there any standard function (maybe Guava) that does this?

Comment: what??? what do you get if you print the "non scaped string"??

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you have this : ***String foo = "I\nam\na\nmultiline\nstring\twith\ttabs";***

Comment: seems like compile time error to me , if you have string like this without proper escaping

Comment: dont you have???

Comment: No, I am given a string foo="I\\n\\am...", assume I can't change this because it is the output of some library function. If you want I can give all the details...

Comment: All details please!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I think OP says the strings *value* is `I\nam\na\nmultiline\nstring\twith\ttabs`, which would be given as `"I\\nam\\na\\nmultiline\\nstring\\twith\\ttabs"` if a Java literal.

Comment: So, Call a string replace and replace every occurrence of "\\" with "\"

Comment: @Andreas check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44764799/escaping-characters-in-a-string#comment76510694_44764799) comment of OP

Comment: I am trying to convert an exception to string and called the printStackTrace method and pass in a ByteArrayOutputStream. When I convert the ByteArrayOutputStream to a String, this is what I get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3537706/5221149). But it depends. Is that a Java-escaped string? Or JavaScript? Or C? Or some other language? They are all mostly the same, but there are differences.

Comment: @Jsleshem that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringEscapeUtils in the apache commons library has many methods that will escape, or unesecape a string as required.

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(someString);
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(someOtherString);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use Apache commons in my project but this looks good.

Comment: @BenjyKessler is it?  Do you have a source?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava-java.lang.String-

Comment: as of 3.6, use commons-text StringEscapeUtils instead, so they want you to use a different package

Answer (score 1):

If you have received the exception from a stack trace, the only escaped characters are probably `\n` and `\t`, in which case:

```
String converted = input.replace("\\n", "\n").replace("\\t", "\t");
```

If there can be more than that I think you'll have to list all the possibilities.

Comment: This will work for my use case but I thought there might be a more generic solution. It's surprising that this doesn't exist since the code clearly exists within the Java compiler.