# Rendering html in android textView

Tags: android, html-table, html-escape-characters

I have tried multiple ways to render html in android . But none of them fulfill my requirement.

In response of a service I got below html message in string.

```
&lt;table id='tblUpdateHistory' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td align='left' colspan='3' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Case Update History&lt;b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left'&gt;&lt;b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Old Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Updated Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;Phone&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;2034947144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;203-494-7144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;",
```

> I am using the given method to render html in textView.

```
public static void setHtml(TextView textView, String bodyData) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(bodyData));
        }
    }
```

I have also tried three ways I handle all EscapeCharacter in my message and replace them appropriately

```
public String handleEscapeCharacter( String str ) {
        String[] escapeCharacters = { "&gt;", "&lt;", "&amp;", "&quot;", "&apos;" ,"&nbsp;"};
        String[] onReadableCharacter = {">", "<", "&", "\"\"", "'" , "\\u00A0"};
        for (int i = 0; i < escapeCharacters.length; i++) {
            str = str.replace(escapeCharacters[i], onReadableCharacter[i]);
        } return str;
    }
```

Then i tried below way

```
public String convertToHtml(String htmlString) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("<![CDATA[");
    stringBuilder.append(htmlString);
    stringBuilder.append("]]>");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

thirdly I tried replace

```
setHtml(tvDetailText, descriptionTemp.replaceAll("(\n|\n\r|\r)", "<br />"));
```

But when I open Notepad++ and replace all escape character and format my message by replacing some character. then i tried it manually it works but only 1 tab is missing. where am i doing wrong. The formatted html is written below.

```
<table 
        id='tblUpdateHistory' 
        cellpadding='0' 
        cellspacing='0' >

            <tr align='left' 
                valign='top' >
                <td align='left' colspan='3' valign='top'><b>Case Update History<b> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr align='left' 
                valign='top' >
                <td class='istColumn' align='left'><b>&amp;nbsp;</b></td>
                <td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'><b>Old Value</b></td>
                <td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'><b>Updated Value</b></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align='left'>
                <td class='istColumn' align='left' valign='top'>Phone</td>
                <td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'>2034947144</td>
                <td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'>203-494-7144</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

I have parsed this json response.

```
{
        "CaseNote": [{
                "ID": 575772,
                "CaseID": 218320,
                "Date": "6/15/2014 3:10:49 PM",
                "Message": "Refunded: Order was never imported/charged due to web issue.  This customer did not want to pickup a different arrangement.",
                "Status": 6,
                "ReOpened": "False",
                "UserName": "",
                "Source": "EAConnect",
                "OriginalRequest": "False"
            }, {
                "ID": 575732,
                "CaseID": 218320,
                "Date": "6/15/2014 3:04:12 PM",
                "Message": "&lt;table id='tblUpdateHistory' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td align='left' colspan='3' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Case Update History&lt;b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left'&gt;&lt;b&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Old Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;&lt;b&gt;Updated Value&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr align='left'&gt;&lt;td class='istColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;Phone&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='secondColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;2034947144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class='thirdColumn' align='left' valign='top'&gt;203-494-7144&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;",
                "Status": 2,
                "ReOpened": "False",
                "UserName": "Jill Bailey",
                "Source": "CallCenter",
                "OriginalRequest": "False"
            }
        ]
        }
```

Second **Message** field in **CaseNotes** and at IOS end it's working fine.

> How to convert this message to **HTML format** ??

**edit 1**

My `HTML response` is not encoding properly I have tested it on codepen.  and tried to encode it using given two methods but all in vain..

```
String firstEncoding = TextUtils.htmlEncode(itemList.get(position).getMessage());
String secondEncoding =  Html.escapeHtml(itemList.get(position).getMessage());
```

Comment: 1 tab is missing. what does it really mean?

Comment: If you are the one behind the service response, I strongly recommend not to exange data in html format, use xml or json instead. So, if this is the case, fix your service first and then render properly, using native controls, on your app.

Comment: check this qustion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview

Comment: @AbdulWaheed In IOS it's working totally fine. But after replacing all escape character by me using Notepad++ still one space is missing as compared to IOS.

Comment: @PedroEmilioBorregoRached No I am not working at service end but the same response is handled correctly at IOS end. What am i doing wrong Or does table is supported in formating in android

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML seems fine except that the first one is escaped. If you have a escaped String and you want to unescape it, you can use [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String str)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java).

Comment: I have edited the question and added two new encoding @AdibFaramarzi

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(itemList.get(position).getMessage()) works but don't show space

Comment: replace spaces with `&nbsp;`.Also check if using your Html.escape (after unscaping) helps.

Comment: so for the getMessage().replaceAll("&nbsp","with_WHAT_I_REPLACE" ??

Comment: By you question I assume that you have spaces (`" "`) and it doesnt show them in HTML and that is why I said replace the `" "` with `&nbsp;` like `replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;")`

Comment: I have &nbsp instead of space and StringEscapeUtils unable to resolve it. other HTML is rendering fine. And Thanks for your valueable feedback

Comment: `&nbps` or `&nbps;`? make sure it has the ;, if not add it to them. You can also replace the `&nbsp;` to `" "` and see if it works.