# How remove single backslash, and replace double backslashes with single ones

Tags: java, regex

What regexp to use to remove the escape characters in the received data.

Examples:

```
dd\.mm\.yyyy -> dd.mm.yyyy
d\-mm\-yy -> d-mm-yyyy
m\\d\\yyyy -> m\d\yyyy
```

Tests:

```
assertEquals("m\\d\\yyyy", removeEscapeChars("m\\\\d\\\\yyyy"));
assertEquals("dd-mm-yyyy", removeEscapeChars("dd\\-mm\\-yyyy"));
assertEquals("dd.mm.yyyy", removeEscapeChars("dd\\.mm\\.yyyy"));
```

Comment: is your second example a typo or why would get the dashes suddenly turn to points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unescape a Java string literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to replace `\x` with `x`. To do that you can use

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
```

- `"\\\\"` as regex represents single `\` created by `"\\"` in string literals
- `.` can represent any character (except line separators, but that shouldn't be a problem based on your example)
- `(.)` will place it in "capturing-group" which will be indexed as `1`
- `$1` in replacement formula, allows us to use current match of group 1 (character matched by `.`, so it would be character which was escaped with `\`).

Comment: If a newline can be escaped then `"(?s)\\\\(.)"` is better.