# Enter a newline character in a text box to be passed into `Matcher.replaceAll()`

Tags: java, android, regex

I am working on adding  search / replace functionality to an android application.

I would like the user to be able to search and replace using regular expressions. The search functionality works correctly, however a newline character in the replacement string `\n` is interpreted as a literal 'n'.

Here is what my code is doing:

```
Pattern.compile(search.getText().toString()).matcher(text).replaceAll(replace.getText().toString())
```

Given

- text is a `CharSequence` with contents `A    \n\n\nB` (note the trailing space after 'A')
- `search` being a textbox with the contents `\s+\n`
- `replace` being a text box with contents `\n`.

I expect the result of the code above to be text = `A\n\n\nB` (trailing spaces removed).

Instead the result is text = `An\n\nB`. i.e. the `\n` in the `replace` text box is interpreted as a literal 'n'.

I would like to know what I can do in order to read the contents of `replace`, such that the `\n` is interpreted as a newline.

Note that I can achieve the desired result in the example by *capturing* the newline like with `search` = `\s+(\n)` and `replace` = $1. This is not, however, the issue.

For the purposes of this discussion I am only considering Unix line endings.

Edit:

using `replace` contents = `\\n` results in a literal '\n' being inserted.

i.e.

```
A    


B
```

is transformed to

```
A\n

B
```

Comment: I think you can use the https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298836 solution.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. Looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721157/enter-a-newline-character-in-a-text-box-to-be-passed-into-matcher-replaceall/64721261#comment114435140_64721157) found in in [stackoverflow.com/a/4298836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298836) works for me.

Essentially, we need to parse the string and replace each escaped character with the correct escaped sequence.

Here is the code I used:

```java
private String unescape(final String input) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean isEscaped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char current = input.charAt(i);
        if (isEscaped) {
            if (current == 't') {
                builder.append('\t');
            } else if (current == 'b') {
                builder.append('\b');
            } else if (current == 'r') {
                builder.append('\r');
            } else if (current == 'n') {
                builder.append('\n');
            } else if (current == 'f') {
                builder.append('\f');
            } else if (current == '\\' || current == '\'' || current == '"') {
                builder.append(current);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal escape sequence.");
            }
            isEscaped = false;
        } else if (current == '\\') {
            isEscaped = true;
        } else {
            builder.append(current);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It isn't as complete or as correct as the solution in the answer linked above, but it appears to work correctly for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The issue here seems to be that '' is itself a special character. You have to double it for regex to see it as a necessary character. Doing a double replacement on all '' should proof useful. like this

```
     yourString = yourString.replace("\", "\\");
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: This can't work because it does not answer the current question. Namely, how to use a newline as a newline char in the literal text used as replacement pattern.