# Parse Correct encoding with Kotlin rest template

Tags: spring, rest, kotlin

I want to get the labels from the wiki api.
And I am using rest template in Kotlin with Spring.
I also tried OKHttp in Java but get the same results.
It worked in Postman.

```
 val uri = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q1726&format=json&props=labels&languages=de|zh"

        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, ByteArray::class.java)
        if (result != null)
            print(String(result, charset("UTF-8")))
```

Output is

```
{"entities":{"Q1726":{"type":"item","id":"Q1726","labels":{"zh":{"language":"zh","value":"\u6155\u5c3c\u9ed1"},"de":{"language":"de","value":"M\u00fcnchen"}}}},"success":1}[B@6a71619f
```

I expect it to be "München" and "慕尼黑"

How to I parse the encoded strings correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java/4298836#4298836) did the trick.

Using [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) from org.apache.commons.text because the other is deprecated.