# Converting Unicode codepoint to Unicode character Java

Tags: java, unicode, discord

I am currently working on a Discord bot that provides stats about a game. My problem is that I can't find a way to convert for example

```
"Cyb |\\u00e2\\u00ad\\u0095\\u00e2\\u0083\\u00a4 LostCube"
```

to a proper name with the Unicode included.

The current output:
[image: the current output]

I tried a bunch of stuff and don't have any idea how to go on. If any of you might a an idea or a solution, please let me know.

Output I'm expecting:
[image: The output I'm expecting]

Comment: See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537745/642706) using *Apache Commons Lang*.

Comment: Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `"Cyb |\u00e2\u00ad\u0095\u00e2\u0083\u00a4 LostCube".encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` returns `'Cyb |⭕⃤ LostCube'`.

Comment: You are expected to perform some research effort before asking a question here. Since you have _"tried a bunch of stuff"_ update your question to detail what you have tried so far. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings use UTF-16 encoding, so you need to use that. You used UTF-8 instead. Encoded in UTF-16, this would be the string you would end up with:

```java
"Cyb |\u2b55\u20e4 LostCube"
```

Comment: The OP used Unicode escapes to (attempt to) encode the bytes, instead of the actual characters (codepoints).