# How to replace backslash but not backslash + n (\n) in Java?

Tags: java, string

Hello I need help replacing "\" character with "/" character in Java.
This is my code:

```
        json = "{\"fields\": {" +
                "                    \"project\":" +
                "                            {" +
                "                                    \"key\": \"key\"" +
                "                            }," +
                "                    \"summary\": \"" + paramMap.get("summary")[0] + "\"," +
                "                    \"description\": \"" + paramMap.get("description")[0].replaceAll("[\r]{1}", "").replaceAll("\n","\\\\n").replace('\\', '/')+ "\"," +
                "                   \"reporter\": {" +
                "                           \"name\": \"" + reporter.getName() + "\"" +
                "        },"+
                "                    \"issuetype\": {" +
                "                            \"id\": \"000000\"" +
                "                    }," +
                something.toString() +
                somethingelse.toString() +
        "   }" +
                "}";
```

This is a mess and I need this JSON not to have backslashes in my text (description). so I added `replace('\\', '/')` there

Unfortunately this turns all new line symbols ("\n") into "/n".
I need to avoid this and also keep the original code
Is there a better way to replace "" in Java OR to exclude "\n" from replacement?
Thanks

**Example stirng**:

Lorem ip\sum dolor sit amet ,

consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et metus eget massa facilisis ultricies sit amet sit amet mi. Donec in hendrerit justo. Ut ut

enim vehicu la metus ullamcorper lacinia sit amet fe ugiat sem. Vivamus t empor eros consequat felis tempus tincidunt. Nullam h endrerit orci dictum dolor volutpat, in maximus lorem imperdiet. Aliquam

tristique nunc nec tellus pretium luctus. Nulla suscipit non magna ac bibendum.

**Desired output**:

Lorem ip/sum dolor sit amet ,

consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et metus eget massa facilisis ultricies sit amet sit amet mi. Donec in hendrerit justo. Ut ut

enim vehicu la metus ullamcorper lacinia sit amet fe ugiat sem. Vivamus t empor eros consequat felis tempus tincidunt. Nullam h endrerit orci dictum dolor volutpat, in maximus lorem imperdiet. Aliquam

tristique nunc nec tellus pretium luctus. Nulla suscipit non magna ac bibendum.

**Actual output**:

Lorem ip/sum dolor sit amet , /nconsectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et metus eget massa facilisis ultricies sit amet sit amet mi. Donec in hendrerit justo. Ut ut /nenim vehicu la metus ullamcorper lacinia sit amet fe ugiat sem. Vivamus t empor eros consequat felis tempus tincidunt. Nullam h endrerit orci dictum dolor volutpat, in maximus lorem imperdiet. Aliquam /ntristique nunc nec tellus pretium luctus. Nulla suscipit non magna ac bibendum.

Comment: Please add several examples like, input line -> expected result

Comment: This is how resulting string looks like after using simple `replace`
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. /nSuspendisse eleifend fringilla ante, eleifend facilisis ne/nque egestas id. Sed ac placerat est, at elementum felis. Donec in /nquam et dolor dictum dignissim ut a quam. Vestibulum id sapien lacus. Donec gr/navida fermentum leo nec pharetra. Suspendisse vitae tempus nulla, et dignissim sem. Vivamus i/npsum massa, aliquet sed finibus in, ullamcorper vel ipsum. Integer porttitor justo id ligula/n pulvinar consequat. D/nonec nunc arcu, feugiat at hendrerit interdum,

Comment: Desired output:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et metus eget massa facilisis
 ultricies sit amet sit amet mi. Donec in hendrerit 

justo. Ut ut enim vehicu
la metus ullamcorper lacinia sit amet fe

ugiat sem. Vivamus t
empor eros consequat felis tempus tincidunt. Nullam h

endrerit orci dictum dolor volutpat, in maximus lorem imperdiet. Aliquam tristique nunc nec tellus pretium luctus. Nulla suscipit non magna ac bibendum. D

Comment: Well it doesnt show new lines in this comment section here but I need a text that doesn't have backslash symbols but still has all special symbols like \n \r etc. So normal  text but all visible backslashes are replaced with forward slashes

Comment: Here is an example https://ideone.com/HJEYPt where the "\n" is not changed. Can you edit your question to include the actual code that produces the errors?

Comment: Take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @matt I look here https://ideone.com/HJEYPt and this is exactly my code. `replace("\\", "/")` results in broken new line characters

Comment: Why? What are these backslashes and where do they come from?

Comment: @J.Doe In the example I pasted, it works fine. The `\n` does not get broken into two characters with the first one being replaced. It absolutely does not be come "/n" if I use `replace("\\", "/");` You need to create a complete compilable example because the behavior you're witnessing doesn't happen, so it is probably something else.

Comment: What it sounds like is you have `String s = "broken\\nlines";`. Then it *is not a newline character* but two characters "\" and "n". You could `string.replace("\\n", "\n");` and get new lines instead of having two characters that *look like* a newline character. How are you getting the string?

Comment: @matt string comes from a web form (JavaScript). Also I updated my question with an actual code piece from my app

Comment: You can check out this quesiton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/how-to-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @matt Unfortunately I'm not allowed to modify the core of this app. Existing JSON structure has to stay. Updated question with example/desired string. Java version is 17. Javax Servlet version is 2.4

Comment: @matt Actual string data comes from a web request. Declaration is `        paramMap = req.getParameterMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> item : paramMap.entrySet()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < item.getValue().length; i++) {
                String logString;
                logString = "[" + item.getKey() + ":" + item.getValue()[i] + "](" + i + ")";
                log.info(logString);
            }
        }`
Maybe I can replace backslash here?

Comment: @matt Are you sure about `translateEscapes`? Doesn't work for me: `Cannot resolve method 'translateEscapes' in 'String'`

Comment: not really sure I understand this right. I need to call `translateEscapes()` on my string variable is this correct? like `someString.translateEscapes()`. Or is it like `var newString = String.translateEscapes(oldString)` ?

Comment: The latter, String is immutable. When you call methods that change the String it returns a new one.

Comment: @matt It didn't work : `[ERROR]   symbol:   method translateEscapes()
[ERROR]   location: class java.lang.String`

Comment: Sounds like you're not using jdk 17 to run your servlet.

Comment: @matt how do I know which version am I using? I didn't design this app. Also is there a solution to my problem if it really isn't jdk 17?

Comment: I meantioned above, replace the escaped characters with their actual characters. ie. `s = s.replace("\\n", "\n");` do that first

Comment: You may want to create a few objects or records allowing you to build the structure you need, and then simply just serialize it to JSON.  Your current approach is brittle and hard to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
somestring.replaceAll("\\\\(?!n)", "/");
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked for me. Shouldve tried this solution first