# How to write 3 bytes unicode literal in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16, utf-32, unicode-literals

I'd like to write unicode literal U+10428 in Java.
http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/U10428/Deseret_Small_Letter_Long_I

I tried with '\u10428' and it doesn't compile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print string literal unicode as the actual character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402877/print-string-literal-unicode-as-the-actual-character)

Comment: the "\u" format is hexidecimal, not decimal.

Comment: I think this is a different question.

Comment: Yes, and it seems that U+10428 is hex. @jtahlborn

Comment: 3-Byte Unicode is a terrible term for U+10000 and above (because 10000 is not bytes). But, if that's what brought you here, you'll probably find your answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because Java went full-out unicode when people thought 64K are enough for everyone (Where did one hear such before?), they started out with UCS-2 and later upgraded to UTF-16.

But they never bothered to add an escape sequence for unicode characters outside the BMP.

Thus, your only recourse is **manually recoding to a UTF-16 surrogate-pair** and using two UTF-16 escapes.

Your example codepoint `U+10428` is `"\uD801\uDC28"`.

I used this site for the recoding: https://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

[Quote from the docs](//docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf):

> #### 3.10.5 String Literals
>
> A string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes. Characters may be represented by escape sequences (§3.10.6) - one escape sequence for characters in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF, two escape sequences for the UTF-16 surrogate code units of characters in the range U+010000 to U+10FFFF.

Comment: In Java, it cannot. Anyway, be careful of "one character": Depending on context (which is sometimes absent or too ambiguous), it can mean anything of byte, codeunit, codepoint and grapheme.